# Draw bitmap on current clip in canvas with border (Paint)

Tags: android, graphics

I'm learning Android by writing a game and have a problem with the graphics API.

I want to draw an image into shape of a Path and then add border on the Path. I was able to clip the image with Path but can't find a way to add border on it. I though it would be simple because the API supports Paint object on Canvas.draw* methods.

**Update**

In original question, my Path contains two rectangles and @christopher-souvey answered correctly. However, I get another problem when dealing with adding one more clipPath() method.

I updated previous code by adding one more circle into Path. Here is my new code:

```
Bitmap srcImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("panda.jpg"));
Bitmap bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcImage.getWidth(), srcImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Path path = new Path();

// This is my border
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapResult);

// Overlay two rectangles
path.addRect(10, 10, 70, 70, Path.Direction.CCW); 
path.addRect(40, 40, 120, 120, Path.Direction.CCW);
canvas.drawPath(path , paint);
canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT);

path.reset();
path.addCircle(40, 80, 20, Path.Direction.CCW); 
canvas.drawPath(path , paint);
canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

// The image is drawn within the area of two rectangles and a circle
// Although I suppose that puting Paint object into drawBitmap() method will add a red border on result image but it doesn't work
canvas.drawBitmap(srcImage, 0, 0, paint);

((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
```

Here is the result from my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j2Kg.png

And this is what I expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKhIr.png

Do I miss anything to make it work ?

Comment: The paint element in drawBitmap is not the Border colour: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Matrix, android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: We can create border with drawRect(), drawCircle() with Paint. How come it doesn't work for drawBitmap()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)` after the drawBitmap
You may have to put in a `canvas.save` before the clip and `canvas.restore` before the drawPath (I'm not sure if the stroke occurs inside or outside the path lines).

Comment: Just for information,the stroke occurs outside of the path lines