# Draw a border (Paint) on current clip (created by different Region.Op)

Tags: android, graphics

I want to draw an image into shape of a Path and then add border on the Path. I was able to clip the image with Path but can't find a way to add border on it. I though it would be simple because the API supports Paint object on Canvas.draw* methods.

I asked another question at: [Draw bitmap on current clip in canvas with border (Paint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314739/draw-bitmap-on-current-clip-in-canvas-with-border-paint) and I accepted the answer. However, after that I found that I need to do a little bit more complicated processing. Because I use two options for clipping instead of one.

Below is my code to clip and image with two different Region.Op parameters

```
Bitmap srcImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("panda.jpg"));
Bitmap bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcImage.getWidth(), srcImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Path path = new Path();

// This is my border
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapResult);

// Overlay two rectangles
path.addRect(10, 10, 70, 70, Path.Direction.CCW); 
path.addRect(40, 40, 120, 120, Path.Direction.CCW);
canvas.drawPath(path , paint);
canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT);

// Draw the circle 
path.reset();
path.addCircle(40, 80, 20, Path.Direction.CCW); 
canvas.drawPath(path , paint);
canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

// The image is drawn within the area of two rectangles and a circle
// Although I suppose that puting Paint object into drawBitmap() method will add a red border on result image but it doesn't work
canvas.drawBitmap(srcImage, 0, 0, paint);

((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
```

Here is the result from my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j2Kg.png

And this is what I expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKhIr.png

Do I miss anything to make it work ?